# Using tidyverse to read data from s3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, readr

I'm trying to read a `.csv` file stored in an s3 bucket, and I'm getting errors. I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/r_kernel/using_r_with_amazon_sagemaker.ipynb), but either it does not work or I am making a mistake and I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
# I'm working on a SageMaker notebook instance
library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)

sagemaker <- import('sagemaker')
sagemaker.session <- sagemaker$Session()

region <- sagemaker.session$boto_region_name
bucket <- "my-bucket"
prefix <- "data/staging"
bucket.path <- sprintf("https://s3-%s.amazonaws.com/%s", region, bucket)
role <- sagemaker$get_execution_role()

client <- sagemaker.session$boto_session$client('s3')
key <- sprintf("%s/%s", prefix, 'my_file.csv')

my.obj <- client$get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

my.df <- read_csv(my.obj$Body) # This is where it all breaks down:
## 
## Error: `file` must be a string, raw vector or a connection.
## Traceback:
## 
## 1. read_csv(my.obj$Body)
## 2. read_delimited(file, tokenizer, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types, 
##  .     locale = locale, skip = skip, skip_empty_rows = skip_empty_rows, 
##  .     comment = comment, n_max = n_max, guess_max = guess_max, 
##  .     progress = progress)
## 3. col_spec_standardise(data, skip = skip, skip_empty_rows = skip_empty_rows, 
##  .     comment = comment, guess_max = guess_max, col_names = col_names, 
##  .     col_types = col_types, tokenizer = tokenizer, locale = locale)
## 4. datasource(file, skip = skip, skip_empty_rows = skip_empty_rows, 
##  .     comment = comment)
## 5. stop("`file` must be a string, raw vector or a connection.", 
##  .     call. = FALSE)
```

When working with Python, I can read a CSV file using someting like this:

```python
import pandas as pd
# ... Lots of boilerplate code
my_data = pd.read_csv(client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'])
```

This is very similar to what I'm trying to do in R, and it works with Python... so why does it not work on R?

Can you point me in the right path?

**Note:** Although I could use a Python kernel for this, I'd like to stick to R, because I'm more fluent with it than with Python, at least when it comes to dataframe crunching.

Comment: Your key is within my_file.csv and cannot be shared correct? Do you have another opportunity to make a reproducible example? Otherwise we can try some remote debugging: What does `typeof(my.obj$Body)` yield. An Environment? Could you share `str(my.obj$Body)` and/or `dput(my.obj$Body)`. My best guess is that its binary data  or wrapped in an environment etc. and need to be converted as its done here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/machine-learning/aws-internal-use-case-evaluating-and-adopting-amazon-sagemaker-within-aws-marketing/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying the `aws.s3` package instead:

https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3

Pretty simple - set your env variables:

```
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "mykey",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "mysecretkey",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1",
           "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = "mytoken")
```

and then once that is out of the way:

`aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, object = "s3://bucket/folder/data.csv")`

Update: I see you're also already familiar with boto and trying to use reticulate so leaving this easy wrapper for that here:
https://github.com/cloudyr/roto.s3

Looks like it has a great api for example the variable layout you're aiming to use:

```
download_file(
  bucket = "is.rud.test", 
  key = "mtcars.csv", 
  filename = "/tmp/mtcars-again.csv", 
  profile_name = "personal"
)

read_csv("/tmp/mtcars-again.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For some reason I can't install devtools on my Jupyter Instance, so I went ahead with `aws.s3` and it worked flawlessly.